# sed syntax error

Tags: shell, sed, centos

I want to replace a forwarder in my named.conf file through a shellscript. The reasons for this are that I have a firewall, and that have to use my localhost in a [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) VM.

I do this

```
forwarder="//        forwarders {10.123.14.2;10.123.14.3;};"
forwarder1="        forwarders {10.123.14.2;10.123.14.3;};"
sed '/'"$forwarder"'/s/'"$forwarder"'/'"$forwarder1"'/'> /etc/named.conf
```

But i get a syntax error.
Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong and present a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Within `sed` the `//` character is special so you have to escape them.

Try something like this for the forwarder string: `forwarder="\/\/`...

Answer (score 1):

Sed can use just about any character to delimit the s/search/replace/ strings, try

```
sed "\@$forwarder@s@$forwarder@$forwarder1@" /etc/named.conf.old > /etc/named.conf
```

Note that your example did not have an input file and if you really executed above line, you have probably zeroed out your `/etc/named.conf`

Modern seds support a `-i` option that will read and save your file *In place*, i.e.

```
sed -i "@......" file
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Will upvote when you change the first `@` to `\@` ;-) (it won't work this way)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker :  Yes, you're right. thanks for the reminder.